# How do I make Python urlib2 to cleverly avoid the security check while trying to log into a site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, urllib2, basic-authentication

I am trying to crawl a website for the first time. I am using urllib2 Python
I am currently trying to log into [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com) social networking site using Python urlib2 and Beautifulsoup. To view a particular page, I need to provide username and password.

So,I followed the [Basic Authentication](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#id6) described on the ducumentation page.

I guess, everything worked well, but the site throws up a security check asking me to type a text (capcha), before sending me the required page. It obviously looks like, the site is detecting that, a page is being requested not by a human, but a crawler.

So, what is the way, to avoid being detected. How to make urllib2 get the desired page, without having to stop at the security check? Pls help..

Comment: If they're asking you to prove that the access is human, they don't want you to use a crawler, do they?

Comment: @Interrobang, why did u simply downvote my question? I badly need to do this, for my research project. So, I thought, there might be a way and somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the foursquare API. I guess, there is  no other way. API are designed for such purposes. 
Crawlers depending solely on the HTML format of the page will fail in the furture when the HTML page changes

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/) instead.